# Click but without ID

Tags: vba, button, click

I have been trying to figure out how to click on this button using VBA

This is what I have

```
 For Each ele In objie.Document.getelementsbytagname("button")(0).Click
    If ele.Value = "butLaunchExcel" Then ele.Click: Exit For
```

This is the inspect code

```
'input class="btn btn-primary" type="button" name="butLaunchExcel" value="Launch Excel" onclick="ExcelLaunch()">
```

Comment: are you asking a question?  .... i think that you wrote it in invisible font.

Answer (score 0):

```
For Each ele In objie.Document.getelementsbytagname("button")
    If ele.Name = "butLaunchExcel" Then 
        ele.Click
        Exit For
    End If
Next ele
```

Comment: For some reason that did not work   I noticed that when I copied the inspect code   it left off a couple of  characters.                                                                                here is the inspect code again <input class="btn btn-primary" type="button" name="butLaunchExcel" value="Launch Excel" onclick="ExcelLaunch()"> == $0

Comment: Does your code enter the loop at all?  If you add `Debug.Print ele.Name` inside the loop what output do you get?

Comment: No I do not  have a loop